# How can I turn sticky edges off when it is already said to be disabled?

Tags: 12.10, display

I went into `Displays` and made sure "Sticky edges" was set to <kbd>OFF</kbd>.  However, it acts as though it is still on!

Where might this setting be hidden? Might there be a way to force it to turn off? It's extremely annoying, as my cursor sticks whenever I move from it from one screen to the next!

I have two monitors, and a GeForce GTX 260 video card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could very well be a driver issue with your graphics. I have a Geforce GT 620 and it wasn't until I messed with the drivers some that I was able to get the little things such as transparency and non-sticky edges to work. Hope this helps!